# How to use Arrays and Returning values

Tags: java, arrays

So, Im creating a program that takes user input, stores it in an array, and then uses the array to do various calculations which it then returns. Ive been working on this for a while and I cannot get it to work. I'm a newbie at this so please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array
{
    public static int getValues(int[] array)
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a series of " +
            array.length + " numbers.");

        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number " +
                (index + 1) + ": ");
            array[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static int getTotal(int[] array) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
            total = total + array[index];
        return total;
    }

    {
        public static int getAverage(int[] array)
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
            average = (total + array[index])/4;
        return average;
    }

    {
        public static int getHighest(int[] array)
        int highest = array[0];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
            highest = index[4];
        return highest;
    }

    {
        public static int getLowest(int[] array)
        int lowest = array[0];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
            lowest = index[0];
        return lowest;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What isn't working? In addition, it looks like your brackets are really messed up. Near your `for` loops and methods. Also you need to state a return type for your members like `public static double getAverage(int[] array){...}`

Comment: There is good tutorial called Language Basics [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html read it and try editing your code until it compiles.

Comment: Your `getTotal` shows that you know how to work with arrays, so I wonder why the other methods are like they are. `average = (total + array[index])/4;` you don't have a `total` variable in that method and why do you divide each array value through *4*? `highest = index[4];` so the highest value is always on index *4*? Then why do you need the `for` loop? `lowest = index[0];` the lowest value is always on index *0*? I suggest that you take a break from your program to "clear your head", because you already know enough to solve that task/assignment.

Comment: Btw: I fixed the indentation of your code ... I hope you notice now that you misplaced almost every brace (`{` and `}`) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have total variable in your main. Also it needs to hold the correct value vefore you call println. I suggest you get rid of the line after the println and write on the line before "int total = getTotal(numbers);" without the quotes ofc. Also your getTotal method returns an int so store it. I didn't check your logic for the rest thought.

Comment: @40Alpha So ive tried to fix up my program and im still having issues it tells me all of my methods have an illegal start of expression.See above for fixed program. Help would be appreciated. Thanks